# How to "copy" Safari Browser History Back-Button Behavior (_blank, close tab)

Tags: javascript

has anyone an idea, how I can copy Apple's Safari Back Button on _blank-Links?

- Click on `taget=_blank` A-Tag
- Opens new tab
- Click on History-Back A-Tag
- Close new Tab, shows original Page

(not my Idea -> design agency)
I have no idea for which keyword I should search, or how this could be done!

Comment: That's a very specific behaviour to Safari, and not really copiable. If another browser *doesn't enable* the back button for you to click on, because it's a new page in a new tab, then you can't hook into the back button behaviour. Furthermore, you should not change the browser's behaviour, it will surprise/confuse users more than it will help them.

Comment: Thank you, thats my mind :-)
Maybe I can talk to the designer...